# Making two branches identical git

Tags: git

Actually, i have two branchs on git. I want them to be identical. However, in the future i want work only on one branch and the changes don't appear on the other branch (branch master is the branch on which i will work and branch V1 is the save).

I did the commands `git checkout master` and `git branch V1`.

Do you know if it is sufficient ?

Thanks,

Comment: Realize that a 'branch' in Git is nothing more than a pointer.  It is a label that points to a specific commit.
Unless you make changes 'on that branch' the pointer (with that name) will ALWAYS reference that commit; which represents the state of your code at that point in the git 'history'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, above steps will be sufficient enough 
With your commands, you first did checkout to the master branch, then git branch branch_name will create a new branch.

To work on the new branch you can again checkout and commit. It won`t affect anything on the master.

Better to git pull master before creating a new branch.
In place of git branch V1, you can use

```
git checkout -b V1
```

this will create and checkout to a new branch

Answer (score 2):

What you did is you obtained a branch `V1` that is in the exact state that branch `master` was when you executed those commands. You "saved" that current state of master into `V1`.

So short answer: **yes it is sufficient** for your requirement.

Nevertheless if "saving a state" is what you are doing, you probably don't really need to do that using a new branch. GIT saves the entire history of commits, so at any time you can simply checkout a past commit and get back to the state you were at that time. Just remember to make frequent commits. Also, you can read about *tags* which will help you mark milestone (for eg. version/release) points during your development.

Also remember to always keep your branches up-to-date before you perform any operations (fetch/pull) unless you specifically do not want that.